# How to use 32 bit Integers for Element Indices in WebGL 1.0?

Tags: webgl, drawing, types

WebGL 1.0 specification does not allow [to create 32-bit index buffers](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1102/msg00093.php). Now I'm in trouble, I'm trying to render huge objects with 100 thousands to 1 million indices. In OpenGL this is no issue at all, and I think it will be no issue in WebGL too, in most cases.

I am not able [to split my data into smaller subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189502/1260906) as I'm already working with split data sets and can't divide it further without breaking up my full program logic.

Now I came across a new extension for WebGL from 2012, [OES_element_index_uint](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/), which looks like it enables unsigned integers (32 bit) for `drawElements` calls.

```
/* draw geometry lines by indices */
gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, getIndexBuffer().length, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, idxBuffer);
```

But when I try to use the `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` I run into the following error:

```
Error: WebGL: drawElements: Invalid `type`: 0x1405
uncaught exception: gl.INVALID_ENUM was caused by call to drawElements
```

How to use 32 bit Integers for Element Indices in WebGL 1.0? How to enable this extension in Chrome or Firefox?

Does this mean in general such a call won't be compatible with most devices running WebGL 1.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling the extension is as simple as:

```
var uints_for_indices = gl.getExtension("OES_element_index_uint");
```

if `uints_for_indices` is null then the extension is not available and you'll have to split your data anyway.

If it's not null then you can now pass `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` for the index type into `gl.drawElements`.

Comment: `OES_element_index_uint` extension is available but it's not rendering the buffers. Strange.

Comment: have you changed the index buffer to store ints?